# jQuery scrollTop / scrollTo / scrollIntoView stops halfway

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well where to start,  i have a site which is all about ranks (users can set their own rank) and whenever a user is logged in it should autoscroll to that displayed rank of the user.

I have a div which gets the id named: fancy whenever the rank matches with the rank of the user.

However this doesn't work as intended because it stops halfway when the fancy div is visible @bottom.

Code parts i tried which failed:

## 1

```
$('body').scrollTo('#fancy',{duration:'slow', offsetTop : '50'});
```

## 2

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#fancy").offset().top - (50)
}, 1000);
```

## 3

```
document.getElementById('fancy').scrollIntoView();
```

Another thing i tried:

- Hide all divs and set the specific rank one to visible, doing this makes the scroll working as intended.

Comment: Can you show it in a fiddle to make it more understandable ?

Comment: That might be little bit hard for me to recreate but i can show it on my site : http://timekillerz.eu/ranks/ it should autoscroll to Gold Nova 1 but it stops halfway before it reached the top.

Comment: Looks like it scroll before images are loaded, so script can't know the real position of #fancy in the page. If i just copy/paste `$('body').scrollTo('#fancy',{duration:'slow', offsetTop : '50'});` in chrome console after page is rendered, it really scroll where it should be. Is your scrollTo in a `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... });` ?

Comment: Oh it looks like the grey boxes are ajax rendered ? can you just try by giving your `div.steamprofile` a fixed height (48 or 50) ?

Comment: Adding fixed height fixed it lil bit more to top. I'm now trying putting a delay on executions.

Comment: @PierreGranger That fixed height did the trick but i had to put it on the td of my table.